# How to get image src for each div with same structure?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ejs

I have multiple same structure div with images. And now I am trying to get src of the image which is clicked.

I have multiple divs with structure like this:

```
<div id="modal" class="model">
    <img id="image" src= "<%= loop.url %>">

    <div class="container">
        <%- loop.title %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get src of the image of the div which is clicked. I am trying the following code for this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.model').forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            captionText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("image").src;
        });
    });
```

But this only gives my src of the first image for all, and not for each image.

I am new to front end development, and I would appreciate any help.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.model').forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            captionText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("image").src;
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="model">
    <img id="image" src= "<%= loop.url %>">

    <div class="container">
        <%- loop.title %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if all elements have the id "image" it's clear. Id's are unique. Beside that, an clickEvent have an "Event" Parameter in and in "Event.target" is the Source Element. You should use that

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz but it gives src of only first image not the ones I click on

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz how to get src of image using Event.target

Comment: An id is supposed to be unique. document.getElementById()  return only one element as per design. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById. 
"The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified, they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.

If you need to get access to an element which doesn't have an ID, you can use querySelector() to find the element using any selector."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to retrieve the first `img` element in the `.modal` div.

`querySelector` works like you might be used to from css. E.g.

- `element.querySelector("img")` selects the first with tag `<img>`
- `element.querySelector(".someclass")` selects the first with a class
- `element.querySelector("#someid")` selects an element with an id

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll(".modal")
  .forEach(
    el => el.addEventListener(
      "click",
      event => {
        const img = el.querySelector("img");
        if (img) console.log(img.src);
      }
    )
  );
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <img src="src1.jpg">
  <p>Image 1</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src2.jpg">
  <p>Image 2</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src3.jpg">
  <p>Image 3</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src4.jpg">
  <p>Image 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("img").click(function(){
   captionText.innerHTML = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

This will work if you have Jquery. If you don't, add this script to your HTML:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: He is adding click to his div ,why you are changing the context here?, and how this got upvoted,and clearly this is not jquery question

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `img` src as below:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.modal', function(event)
{
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <img src="src1.jpg" alt="im1">
  <p>Image 1</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src2.jpg" alt="im2">
  <p>Image 2</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src3.jpg" alt="im3">
  <p>Image 3</p>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <img src="src4.jpg" alt="im4">
  <p>Image 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see if I can run getElementById on item but it doesn't have such function. It does have getElementsByTagName so you can reference the img elements inside item

```
let captionText = document.getElementById('captionText')

document.querySelectorAll('.model').forEach(function(item) {
    let currentSrc = item.getElementsByTagName('img').item(0).src
    item.addEventListener('click', function(x) {
        captionText.innerHTML = currentSrc;
    });
});
```